# asp.net mvc validation problem

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

This doesn't make any sense to me.

Look at this ViewModel:

```
public class SelectService
{
    [Required]
    public int? SelectedServiceId { get; set; }
}
```

Look at this Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult SelectService()
{
    TryUpdateModel(WizardContainer.SelectService, "SelectService");
    TryValidateModel(WizardContainer.SelectService, "SelectService"); // if I remove this, ModelState.IsValid will always be true


    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("OtherAction");
    }
    else
    {
        return View(WizardContainer);
    }
}
```

Now read this exceprt from Apress ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework by S. Sanderson:

> Whenever you use model binding to populate a model object—either by receiving it as an action method
>   parameter, or by calling UpdateModel() or TryUpdateModel() manually—then DefaultModelBinder will
>   automatically run the validators associated with all model objects that it has updated (i.e., ones where it
>   has set a value on at least one property).
>   If you update a model object in any other way, its validators will not be run unless you explicitly tell
>   the framework to run them.

So, why then is validation never occuring when I call TryUpdateModel()? To get validation to occur, I have to explicitly validate using TryValidateModel().

### UPDATE

Here is a very similar action in the same controller that works as expected:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Index(string nextButton)
{
    TryUpdateModel(WizardContainer.Index);

    if (nextButton != null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("OtherAction");
    }
    else
    {
        return View(WizardContainer.Index);
    }
}
```

And here is it's ViewModel:

```
public class Index
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime? SelectedServiceTime { get; set; }
}
```

### Update 2

I changed some things and now it behaves as expected, but I still don't understand why.

Look at the edited action:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult SelectService()
{
    TryUpdateModel(WizardContainer.SelectService);
    //TryValidateModel(WizardContainer.SelectService, "SelectService"); // not needed anymore

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("OtherMethod");
    }
    else
    {
        return View(WizardContainer.SelectService);
    }
}
```

The difference now being only that the object that I am passing to TryUpdateModel() is the object I am passing to the view instead of being a property of the object that I pass to the view. What the deal yo?

Comment: What happens if you use an int instead of nullable int? You're marking a nullable parameter as required which doesn't make sense in terms of a web request because nullable means no value provided at all (parameter not included in the request). Permitting null values but marking the property Required creates conflicting validation logic.

Comment: @Nathan - You can't require a value type. It will always have a value. You're supposed to use a nullable int.

Comment: @Bigglesby Okay, I didn't consider that. Good point.

Comment: Have you perhaps set a custom modelbinder that does not automatically perform the validation?

Comment: @Adrian - No chance of that. I haven't registered any other model binders and I haven't decorated any custom models to use any other binders.

Comment: Can you recreate the problem with a different model?

Comment: @Nathan - Haven't tried to recreate the problem, but I do have a very similar action method in the same controller that works properly. See my update in just a moment.

Comment: See my new update. This is irritating.

Comment: @Bigglesby:  Could it be a type issue?  The validators are pulled via reflection...

Comment: @Dave - What do you mean? (I am Bigglesby)

Comment: Are WizardContainer.Index and WizardContainer.SelectService the exact same type?

Comment: The 2nd parameter in TryValidate, the prefix, is probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've included both the `TryUpdateModel` and `TryValidateModel` method decompilations below.  The primary difference I see is that the return of `TryUpdateModel` is `ModelState.IsValid`, but I see no explicit execution of the validators in `TryUpdateModel`.

`TryValidateModel` actually gets the validators and executes each one.  There must be some subtle difference between your working and non-working cases.  I can't say what the root cause is, but in your working case there are already `ModelState` errors added to the `ModelState.Errors` collection when you call `TryUpdateModel`.  (`ModelState.IsValid` returns false if there are one or more errors in the `ModelState.Errors` collection.)

TryUpdateModel:

```
protected internal bool TryUpdateModel<TModel>(TModel model, string prefix, string[] includeProperties, string[] excludeProperties, IValueProvider valueProvider) where TModel: class
{
    if (model == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("model");
    }
    if (valueProvider == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("valueProvider");
    }
    Predicate<string> predicate = delegate (string propertyName) {
        return BindAttribute.IsPropertyAllowed(propertyName, base.includeProperties, base.excludeProperties);
    };
    IModelBinder binder = this.Binders.GetBinder(typeof(TModel));
    ModelBindingContext context2 = new ModelBindingContext();
    context2.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(delegate {
        return base.model;
    }, typeof(TModel));
    context2.ModelName = prefix;
    context2.ModelState = this.ModelState;
    context2.PropertyFilter = predicate;
    context2.ValueProvider = valueProvider;
    ModelBindingContext bindingContext = context2;
    binder.BindModel(base.ControllerContext, bindingContext);
    return this.ModelState.IsValid;
}
```

TryValidateModel:

```
protected internal bool TryValidateModel(object model, string prefix)
{
    if (model == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("model");
    }
    foreach (ModelValidationResult result in ModelValidator.GetModelValidator(ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(delegate {
        return model;
    }, model.GetType()), base.ControllerContext).Validate(null))
    {
        this.ModelState.AddModelError(DefaultModelBinder.CreateSubPropertyName(prefix, result.MemberName), result.Message);
    }
    return this.ModelState.IsValid;
}
```

Comment: I think you are asking a question. In the working method, ModelState.IsValid = true before trying to update the model. If the required value isn't supplied in the request, then it is false.

Comment: Validation doesn't occur in the body of TryUpdateModel() itself, but rather in the resulting call to DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(), which calls BindProperty() where the Errors are actually registered in ModelState.